# javascript set header Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, request-headers

I'm testing JS with POST. But I didn't get success with that.

Using the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div>
testing js...
</div>

<script>
function upload() {
    var method = "POST";
    var url = "http://127.0.0.1:9000/push";

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.open(method, url);

    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain;charset=UTF-8");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    
    var text = {"command":"PUSH"};
    xhr.send(text);

}         
upload();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I'm getting the following error:

[image]

The weird is that the request header is not being set correctly through the line:

```
xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
```

The request header is like this:

[image]

Comment: You have to enable cross origin access on your server too.

Comment: `xhr.setRequestHeader` — It's a **response** header, not a request header!

Comment: "The weird is that the request header is not being set correctly" — Since it isn't a safe header to put on a request, the browser is asking the server for permission before it does … but as noted above, it doesn't belong on the request in the first place.

Comment: `var text = {"command":"PUSH"};` —That's an object, not text.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the XHR response:
Access-Control-Allow-Origin IS present, 
Origin is null because you are executing it from your local system, upload to a server to see origin populated.

```js
function upload() {
    var method = "POST";
    var url = "http://127.0.0.1:9000/push";

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.open(method, url);

    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain;charset=UTF-8");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

    var text = {"command":"PUSH"};
    xhr.send(text);

}

$(document).ready(function(){
$('.upload').click(upload);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="upload">Upload</button>
```

Comment: While that will cause the browser to send an `Origin` header, the question was about the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header (which doesn't belong on the request in the first place).

Comment: Access-Control-Allow-Origin IS present, but origin cannot be determined.

Comment: You trouble is in your server side. you need to allow any origins (*) and also check because you're sending an object so you need to set in you request that you're sending a json.

Comment: This answer is very misleading. Setting `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header on request is totally useless